Beef and buffalo meat is mentioned to be offered to ancestors?
In Apasthamba Dharma sutras, 2.7.16 it's mentioned


Beef satisfies (the Manes) for a year,[11]

Buffalo's (meat) for a longer (time) than that.

By this (permission of the use of buffalo's meat) it has been declared that the meat of (other) tame and wild animals is fit to be
offered.



Cow ( Go mata ) is highly respected as per scriptures. Shri Krishna says to uddhava in Uddhav Gita that those who serve and worship feed cows is considered as devotional service .
But in Apasthamba sutras it's mentioned to use Beef and meat in shraddhas ?
Is this really authentic ? Because Gohatya is a very huge sin as per scriptures

Post dvapara yuga the mantra recite had lost the power of mantras, those day sacrifice are done to show all those who have done yagnya have got the desired result, on killing and offering in yagya or havan.. people can she the jiva in cow transformed to light(devatha by power of mantra) is that possible in todays world no way that is why yagnya with animal sacrifice to be avoiaded.

Similar verses can be found in many scriptures for example in Manu Smriti:

3.267. The ancestors of men are satisfied for one month with sesamum grains, rice, barley, masha beans, water, roots, and fruits, which
have been given according to the prescribed rule,
3.268. Two months with fish, three months with the meat of gazelles, four with mutton, and five indeed with the flesh of birds,
3.269. Six months with the flesh of kids, seven with that of spotted deer, eight with that of the black antelope, but nine with that of the
(deer called) Ruru,
3.270. Ten months they are satisfied with the meat of boars and buffaloes, but eleven months indeed with that of hares and tortoises,
3.271. One year with cow-milk and milk-rice; from the flesh of a long-eared white he-goat their satisfaction endures twelve years.
3.272. The (vegetable called) Kalasaka, (the fish called) Mahasalka, the flesh of a rhinoceros and that of a red goat, and all kinds of
food eaten by hermits in the forest serve for an endless time.

Now on 271, Medhatithi comments that it can also refer to cow meat not just a preparation made from cow milk. See his commentary given below:

As between direct and indirect connection, the former being more
authoritative, we construe ‘gavyena’—‘cow’s’—with ‘payasā,’ ‘milk and
not with ‘māṃsa,’ ‘meat,’ which forms the subject-matter of the
context.
Others, however, explain the particle ‘ca’ as having a cumulative force, and then explain the passage to mean, ‘meat of the cow, and
milk or milk-rice.’
‘Pāyasa,’ ‘milk-preparations,’ stands for curds and such things, as
also rice cooked in milk.
‘Vārdhrīṇasa’—is old goat. The scriptures describe it as follows
s—‘Drinking with three, devoid of sense-virility and white,—such a
goat has been called Vārdhriṇasa by persons learned in sacrifices, in
connection with sacrificial rituals.’ That goat is called ‘drinking
with three’ who wets his tongue and two ears, while drinking water.
The Expiatory Rite that Śaṅkha has prescribed in connection with the
eating of beef, should be understood to apply to eating apart from the
‘Madhuparka’ offering and from the ‘Aṣṭakā’ Śrāddhas.—(271)

If we see Manu 3.271 with the Apasthambha verse you have given, together, then Medhatithi's comment appears true.
Also while killing cows is a heinous crime in Hinduism but when killing is done as part of rites  meant for Devas or Pitrus then no sins are involved. This is the position of all Hindu scriptures. Killing outside of sacrifice/rites is a sin.

Okay . If there are flaws in scriptures like Manu smriti and Apasthamba Dharma sutras, does it mean remaining teachings and text are also flawed or other teachings may still be genuine?

There are no flaws @Karthik

Hi @Rickross, Sir I have one question. Can you please answer this question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61678/what-will-happen-if-two-universal-laws-are-conflicting-with-each-other Thanks.
