What will happen if Two Universal Laws are conflicting with each other?
Namasthe
My question is there are so many Laws in this Universe right .
What will happen if two Laws conflict with each other??
Let's take an example, suppose there is Law of Karma and assume there is some other Law regarding promises
NOTE:-
Please kindly assume this scenario for my question POV. This is not real . This is just a hypothetical situation where I want to know if Two Laws contradict with each other what will happen in that case?
Let's take an example, suppose there is Law of Karma and assume there is some other Law regarding promises

Law 1:- Law Of Promise
As Per this, If you put a promise with some condition and if you break it, What you put in that condition will manifest and becomes true
For example, if I make a promise with a condition
such that If I break the oath of celibacy, my father will get
Adhogati and remain in lower Yonis for eternity. If I break the vow of celibacy my father should get born in lower yoni for eternity and never get human birth as per this Law


Law 2:- Law Of Karma

As per This Law , The Law of Karma dictates that every soul
experiences
consequences solely based on their own actions (karma)

So if I break my oath of celibacy, my father is supposed to rot in lower Yonis for eternity as per Law of promise (Law 1)
But as per Law of Karma (Law 2) he has to get a human life in some birth or other . He won't permanently rot in lower Yonis for eternity if he has not done such huge bad karma to deserve it and eventually have to get a human birth
Both Law of promise and Law of Karma are contradictory with each other . As per law of promise he should never get human birth for eternity which contradicts law of Karma where he has to get a human birth eventually sooner or later
So in this case what would happen.?
